# Stateful user-space firewall for Linux

Tags: iptables, firewall

Is there any stateful **user-space** firewall for Linux?
I'm looking for a firewall that doesn't rely on anything in Linux kernel (like iptables/netfilter) and works with raw packets.

Comment: A firewall, even in user-space would require the network stack to provide hooks from the kernel anyway to the user-space, which to my understanding would prove highly insecure, impractical and slow, in one word: dangerous. Unless you don't mind reimplementing the network stack in user space I'm afraid it's very unlikely to impossible. I need someone with more advanced knowledge to confirm though.

Comment: Thank you, I'm planning to use Intel DPDK, so I really don't need the kernel stack. Firewall should work with raw packets.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables` will allow you to route selected packets to usespace for additional processing. (In your case *selected packets* would possibly mean *all packets*.) I've not done this but `man iptables` has this to say on the matter:

> TARGETS
>
> ACCEPT means to let the packet through. DROP means to drop the packet
>   on the floor. **QUEUE means to pass the packet to userspace.** (How the
>   packet can be received by a userspace process differs by the
>   particular queue handler. 2.4.x and 2.6.x kernels up to 2.6.13 include
>   the ip_queue queue handler. Kernels 2.6.14 and later additionally
>   include the nfnetlink_queue queue handler. **Packets with a target of
>   QUEUE will be sent to queue number '0' in this case. Please also see
>   the NFQUEUE target as described later in this man page.**)

and later,

> **NFQUEUE [...] is an extension of the QUEUE target.** As opposed to
>   QUEUE, it allows you to put a packet into any specific queue,
>   identified by its 16-bit queue number. [...] it requires the
>   nfnetlink_queue kernel support.

Of course, this doesn't give you stateful firewall support but at least you can get at the packets. This also uses `iptables` to get the packets out to you in the first place, which may be unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know this. What I try to achieve is bypass kernel altogether with DPDK. So I can't use netfilter/iptables.

Comment: @Konstantin you're probably going to need to use the `tap` interface then. (See OpenVPN for one example of how this can be used to process packets entirely in userspace.)

Comment: tap is very very slow, it would be great to bypass the kernel altogether and do everything in user-space